# Homepage "active" questions sorting glitch

Tags: bug, sorting, homepage

There seems to be a small bug that can cause inconsistent order of the active questions list on the homepage:

[image]

This is the first time I see that. This was on electronics.stackexchange. The inconsistency was already there a few seconds before I refreshed the page and took the screenshot, but was fixed after refreshing a few minutes later.

Comment: Pretty sure the items list itself is cached for a minute or so, so the server won't have to reload everything.