# Are users' reputation scores on the home page supposed to stand out that much now?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design, homepage

It seems a couple minutes ago, a change was applied to the styling of the homepage, with users' rep scores now being much darker (and standing out more):

> [image: new look of the homepage]

Compare with the former light grey colouring (image courtesy of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330027/398063)):

> [image: former look, scores written in light gray]

Is this intentional? If so, why? It highlights something that's not really relevant, in my opinion.

Comment: Higher contrast ratios make for better accessibility.

Comment: @Sonic if that's the reason, I'd be interested in knowing why the accessibility focus was put on users' rep - stuff like votes sounds way more important to me

Comment: Due to the color change, reputation look like more important than username. I don't think reputation is that important information.

Comment: What? Isn't this site all about reputation?

Comment: @rene no, unicorns! https://i.stack.imgur.com/73FOC.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for the UI regression. This has been fixed.

Comment: Just curious, what went wrong?

Comment: Style regression when [refactoring out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343758/51) old custom css stuff in favor of Stacks standardization.