# Reputation score in homepage view is too overwhelming

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design, homepage

Just noticed a change in the homepage view, making the reputation of the users both black and bold:

> [image: Home page with bold and black reputation score]

I find it too distracting. Can it please be changed? If the purpose is to make the score stick out, just having it black and not bold is enough:

> [image: Homepage with black but non bold reputation score]

Can this please be changed?

Comment: We now. Being fixed.

Comment: Wow, fastest tag change ever. Kudos, @Yaakov! :D

Comment: Was already [reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343856/51), fix already committed, pushing to live in a few

Comment: Sorry for the UI regression. This has been fixed.

Comment: @Yaakov all good! Thanks a lot for the quick fix. :)

Comment: @YaakovEllis did the badge count on your profile also turn bold? The numbers within the coloured boxes?

Comment: @Luuklag I don't know. If it did, please report it in a different post.

Comment: @YaakovEllis https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343878/regression-in-badge-count-design-on-profile-page